# Junit test for Bigquery in java

Tags: java, testing, junit, google-bigquery, mockito

I'm trying to write Junit test cases for BigQuery using Mockito and Junit5. I'm trying to mock or even initialize Table but am not able to do so is there any way we can do it

```
 private JsonStreamWriter streamWriter;

    void WriteToBQ(TableName parentTable) {
            BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions
                    .newBuilder()
                    .setProjectId(AppConstants.PROJECT_ID)
                    .build()
                    .getService();
    
            Table table = bigquery.getTable(parentTable.getDataset(), parentTable.getTable());
            Schema schema = table.getDefinition().getSchema();
    
            TableSchema tableSchema = BqToBqStorageSchemaConverter.convertTableSchema(schema);
    
            streamWriter = JsonStreamWriter.newBuilder(parentTable.toString(), tableSchema).build();
        }
```

I tried initialise and mock Table using

```
 table = new Table(bigquery, new TableInfo.BuilderImpl(TABLE_INFO));
```

but I can't use BuilderImpl outside the package as  not being public

I have even tried to Mock Table, but still no luck

```
        bigquery = mock(BigQuery.class);
        mockOptions = mock(BigQueryOptions.class);
        table = mock(Table.class);
        when(bigquery.getTable(any(),any())).thenReturn(table);
        when(bigquery.getOptions()).thenReturn(mockOptions);
```

Comment: You can't mock an object which is created inside the method scope that you're testing, you could change the method to have`BigQuery` object as a parameter, that way you can mock

Comment: What about the table ?

Comment: `bigquery.getTable` can't be mocked here So the `table` would have the value that the actual method returns

Comment: You can't actually get the table details with test details as it will give the response as a bad request. So can't call getTable() method we might need to mock this

Answer (score 0):

If I had to write the test for this scenario, I would go making a slight change to the class, I would extract the `BigQuery` object creation and move it to a protected method like the one below and override the Object creation in test implementation

```
public class Writer {
    private JsonStreamWriter streamWriter;

    void WriteToBQ(TableName parentTable) throws Descriptors.DescriptorValidationException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        BigQuery bigquery = buildBigQueryService();

        Table table = bigquery.getTable(parentTable.getDataset(), parentTable.getTable());
        Schema schema = table.getDefinition().getSchema();

        TableSchema tableSchema = BqToBqStorageSchemaConverter.convertTableSchema(schema);

        streamWriter = JsonStreamWriter.newBuilder(parentTable.toString(), tableSchema).build();
    }

    protected BigQuery buildBigQueryService(){
        return BigQueryOptions
                .newBuilder()
                .setProjectId("AppConstants.PROJECT_ID")
                .build()
                .getService();
    }
}
```

The test should be something like

```
class WriterTest {
    BigQuery bigquery;
    Table table;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        bigquery = mock(BigQuery.class);
        table = mock(Table.class);
        when(bigquery.getTable(any(), any())).thenReturn(table);
    }

    @Test
    public void testWriteToBQ() throws Descriptors.DescriptorValidationException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        TableName tableName = TableName.newBuilder().setTable("A").build();
        Writer writer = new MockWriter();
        writer.WriteToBQ(tableName);
    }

    class MockWriter extends Writer {
        @Override
        protected BigQuery buildBigQueryService() {
            return mock(BigQuery.class);
        }
    }

}
```

Here in the `MockWriter`, I have just overridden the `buildBigQueryService` which gives mock `BigQuery.class` other functionalities that remain the same as the parent class

Also, it is not recommended to mock data so please consider build real table object instead of this
`table = mock(Table.class);`

Comment: Its didn't work for me "when(bigquery.getTable(any(), any())).thenReturn(table);" line is giving me the error

Comment: what was the error?